# Make Fragment appear first in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am building parts of my `layout` programmatically.

My process looks like this:

- I inflate a layout: `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_layout, viewGroup, false);`
- I add this view to the ViewGroup: `viewGroup.addView(view);`

Before adding views in this way, I first add a fragment to the `root` view of `viewGroup`:

- `getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.viewgroup_root, fragment,  "fragment_tag").commit();`

My `ViewGroup` is a `LinearLayout` and I am adding the `Fragment` **before** I add the other views. However, the `Fragment` is appearing **last** - after all the views I add using `ViewGroup.addView()`.

How can I get the added `Fragment` to be displayed **first** in the `LinearLayout`, and *why* is the LinearLayout displaying it last if it was added first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`commit()` is asynchronous - it does not run immediately. Therefore you definitely *are* running your `addView` methods before your fragment is actually added.

As Fragments automatically are re-added to their respective layout based on ID and you do not control the ordering of when the fragment is added to the layout in those cases, you can't rely on any initial ordering.

Instead, you should always add a Fragment to its own container - if using [Fragment `1.2.0`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.2.0) or higher (the latest right now is `1.2.5`), you should add a `FragmentContainerView` to your `LinearLayout`. If you're using an earlier version of Fragments, you'd want to add a `FrameLayout` to your `LinearLayout`. In either case, you'd need to make sure you use `setId()` with that layout and use the same ID when you use `add`.

Comment: Great explanation of `commit` and why it was appearing last, and solid solution!

Comment: This is better answer then mine. One thing I have to add though is not just FrameLayout works. For example would work with RelativeLayout as well, and height not necessarily should be match_parent - can even be dynamic like 0dp with weight 1 (if parent is LinearLayout)

Comment: @ror - what layout params you use on your fragment container is entirely independent of what the container is (`layout_` params are for the parent, not for the view itself). As Fragments are always added as `match_parent`/`match_parent` to their container, `RelativeLayout` is only going to make your app slower - you only need the simple layout algorithm of `FrameLayout` (and preferably, the fixes added in `FragmentContainerView`, which extends `FrameLayout`) for the container of your fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to leave placeholder under your `LinearLayout` and use placeholder's ID to do beginTransaction/add stuff. Any viewgroup would do. You are not just adding another view to your viewgroup, you are adding a fragment. It has its own lifecycle, bound to entities hosting it (activity, fragment).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit about the placeholder that you mentioned?